# Class instance's field is not showing the stored value of that field

Tags: c#, class, network-programming, inputstream, instance-variables

I am developing a file sending application from one end system(Client Class) to another end system(Server Class), currently I am testing it on same pc.

I am able to transfer the file from client to server but the problem is with the extension of that file which is being received on server, Now to solve this problem I have used a string variable which store the type of extension  in client class and by referencing the client class I am able to use that variable in server class.

Now the problem is,

> When I use the variable(cl.extension) in server class then it returns no value.

Code of Client class

```
    namespace Client_App
 {

public partial class Clients : Form
{

    public string extension;
    //Create the instance of TcpClient Class so that we can use the methods and properties of that class
    TcpClient clientsocket = new TcpClient();
    public Clients()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //It connect client to the specified server with the ip address and the port number
        //By here the server replies that the connection has been established after executing the next statement
        clientsocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);

        label2.Text = "From Server: Connected ";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here GetStream method send the message to the server
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientsocket.GetStream();


        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        ofd.AddExtension = true;

        string filename = ofd.FileName;
        byte[] outStream = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    //Variable that store the extension of file
        extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        serverStream.Write(outStream , 0, outStream.Length);
        textBox2.Text = "File has been sended to server";

        serverStream.Flush();

    }

}
 }
```

Code of Server Class

```
    using Client_App;
public partial class Server : Form
{

    Clients cl = new Clients();


    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            try
            {
                serverSocket.Start();
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] inStream = new byte[69000];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
     //After reading the stream, it give user ability to save that stream by creating a file
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.ShowDialog();
            DicrectoryBox.Text = sfd.FileName + cl.extension;//Here is problem
            MessageBox.Show(cl.extension);//It does not show the extension (of client file)

            File.WriteAllBytes(DicrectoryBox.Text, inStream);
            StatusBox.Text = "Writing Completed";
        }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }



        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
    }
}
```

> Problem is with cl.extension in server class, MessageBox is not showing the extension of the file that has been sanded by client.

Comment: The cl instance of the Clients class in the server block has nothing to do with the instance of the Clients class that sends the info. You are creating a new instance of the Clients. In this instance the extension property has not been set.

Comment: I have included the Client Class by using (using projectName) namespace and then I have created the instance of the class.

Comment: Show how do you start the client and the server program.  This will be helpful to explain my comment above